# Opening a simple file using OS in python

Tags: python

Python code

```
import os
def open_ss():
    os.startfile('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe')
```

Error message

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jong\Desktop\Projects\MiniScript\main.py", line 5, in open_ss
    os.startfile('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe'
```

Why is the file specified showing up as "C:\\WINDWOS\\system\\SnippingTool.exe"
instead of just "C:\WINDWOS\system\SnippingTool.exe"

Comment: use subprocess.call

Comment: i get the same error

Comment: In Python the backslash character is an escape character. So when using it in a file path, it too has to be escaped in order to find a file, hence the double backslashes.

Comment: So how can I fix the url 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\SnippingTool.exe' inorder for it to work?

Comment: Make it a raw string: `os.startfile(r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe')`

Comment: Its giving me the same error still

Comment: It seems that this particular problem only occurs when trying to open SnippingTool. It works fine when I try to open mspaint or notepad.